# How to merge linq queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a class which is self-referenced.

```
public class MyPerfectClass 
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public MyPerfectClass? Parent { get; set; }

    private readonly List<MyPerfectClass> _children = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<MyPerfectClass> Children => _children.AsReadOnly();
}
```

I need to get all 'MyPerfectClass' where ChildItem's IsActive is true. I can write two seperate queries but can't get parents & childrens based on childrens filtering. Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add your work so far in an edit to this question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question seems unclear. Do you want to get all objects where the parent has at least one child with IsActive == true? "ChildItem" is not defined anywhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
List<MyPerfectClass> parentsList = new List<MyPerfectClass>();
var results = parentsList.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.IsActive));
```

ALL, ANY and other queries can be used on nestled objects.

MyPerfectClass having an instance of MyPerfectClass to define parent seems a little off. The Parent object instance on the MyPerfectClass may not share the children defined on MyPerfectClass where parent is defined. May lead to confusion.